# Close Div On Click Outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently designing a website in which a user clicks on a button and an overlay and box fades in with various contents. When the user either clicks a close button or clicks outside the box, the box and all the contents fade out. Here's a little bit of code I've already produced:

HTML

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="specialBox">
    <p style="text-align: center">Special box content.</p>
    <button type="button" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close Overlay</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#overlay {
    background: #000;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
div#specialBox {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 425px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    overlay.style.opacity = .8;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

jQuery (may be incorrect syntax)

```
$('html').click(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('#specialBox').***IS_VISIBLE***) {
        $("#specialBox").fadeOut(300);
        $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```

An example can be found on http://www.madeon.fr when you click on "Newsleter". You can both click a close button and click outside to close it. Now, my question is how can I achieve that with my work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the main problem. I simply deleted my jQuery and added "onmousedown='toggleOverlay()'" as an attribute to div#overlay. Then when I clicked the overlay the box disappeared.

Here's the new HTML:

```
    <div id="overlay" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()"></div>
```

Comment: Consider using jQuery for more than one function if you are going to use the library. Its 94kb compressed :) The solution below demonstrates how simple it can be to use it all the way through.

Comment: Also, 33 people viewed this question.. thats 33 people who were willing to help.. maybe take a little extra time next time and debug a little thing like that on your own and save the real questions for the generous folks of stackoverflow :) just a suggestion

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way: using  `$(document).click`

The below jsfiddle is for your help: http://jsfiddle.net/jec7rmw6/2/

```
    function toggleOverlay(){
        if($("#specialBox").is(":visible"))
        {
            $('#specialBox').fadeOut(300);
        }
    }

    jQuery('#specialBox').click(
        function (e) { 
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    );

    $(document).click(function() {
        if($("#specialBox").is(":visible"))
        {
            $('#specialBox').fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Alright, I didn't change the function, but when I changed the jQuery and tested it, the box immediately disappears. I was wanting that to stay visible until I either clicked the button or clicked outside the box. You're definitely on the right track, though.

Comment: When thinking logically, I know that when the page loads the box is invisible. If I click on the button, the box is visible. If I click outside the box when it is visible, the box disappears.

Comment: You need to actually prevent bubbling using stopPropagation